# React Apollo: How to use the result of the same query on multiple places

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

We are wondering if we understand the way how to query in apollo right. Our goal is very simple: We need data from graphQL on 2 different places in our app. Both places needs the information of the finished result and the information if the data is ready or not.

So the question is now what is the best way to do this in apollo ? We were not able to find an example in the docs.

1. The same query
   We thought the same query would do this job. So we wrapped our components with the same graphql HOC with the same Query in it.

Problem: This will cause that the query will executed twice. I mean - of course - because we call it twice. But we thought that apollo will notice that we are calling the same query with the same parameter.

2. Storing in own store
   Would it be necessary to store the information in our own redux store ? If yes we would need to wrap our first component with the query and store the information if its still loading and the result of the query.
3. Access the apollo store
   Is there a recommended way to wrap the component with another HOC to get the apollo store ? How would you access the correct query with the information of "is still fetching" and the "result" ?

We would be happy if we could it do like described in 1 but as far as we see this is not possible. It would be nice if you can tell me what would be the Apollo-Way of doing this

**Edit**
The Problem we have is not solved yet. I've found this issue on github. So they know that this is a "problem" yet but did not solve it yet. So we will need to change our logic of components and calling queries.

Reference:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/646

Answer (score 0):

We're using the same Higher-Order Component (HOC) approach and it's working well.

If your goal is to avoid calling the same query twice, you can set your [`fetchPolicy`](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy) to one of the other options that only pulls from the cache.

That said, are you sure the query is actually being called twice over the network? Or is the action only being called twice with no network request (check your `Network` tab in Chrome dev tools)?

The default behavior of Apollo is `cache-first`, so it's possible that you're seeing the action but not an actual network request:

> cache-first: This is the default value where we always try reading data from your cache first. **If all the data needed to fulfill your query is in the cache then that data will be returned. Apollo will only fetch from the network if a cached result is not available.** This fetch policy aims to minimize the number of network requests sent when rendering your component.

**Update:** another option would be [query batching](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862), which should solve this problem.

Comment: Hey. Yes we are sure that its called twice because we saw the logs on our graphql server. As far as I understand your quoted message it will get the data from the cache when the data is already there. But what if the data is not ready yet and another component is calling the same query ? Because this is our case.  So in our case 2 components will call the query at a time where the data is not yet ready and the goal would be that both components will show a "Loading" or "Pending" state.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. @TJR have you tried query batching? https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862